# Scipy: Trying to write wav file, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, arrays, audio, scipy, anaconda

I am using Anaconda3 and SciPy to try to write a wav file using an array:

`wavfile.write("/Users/Me/Desktop/C.wav", 1000, array)`

(I don't know how many samples per second, I'm planning on playing around with that, I'm betting on 1000 however)

`array` returns an array of 3000 integers, so the file would last 3 seconds.

However it gives me this error when trying to run:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ce3a8d3e4b4b> in <module>()
----> 1 wavfile.write("/Users/Me/Desktop/C.wav", 1000, fin)

/Users/Me/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py in write(filename, rate, data)
213 
214     try:
--> 215         dkind = data.dtype.kind
216         if not (dkind == 'i' or dkind == 'f' or (dkind == 'u' and data.dtype.itemsize == 1)):
217             raise ValueError("Unsupported data type '%s'" %         data.dtype)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing `write` an ordinary python list, which does not have an attribute called `dtype` (you can get that info by studying the error message). The documentation of `scipy.io.wavfile` clearly states you should pass it a numpy array:

> Definition:  wavfile.write(filename, rate, data)
>
> Docstring:
>
> Write a numpy array as a WAV file

You can convert your ordinary python list to a numpy array like so:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(array)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there was a difference between numpy arrays and normal python lists, thanks man.

Comment: Wait, now its giving me a ValueError: `Unsupported data type 'object'` ?

Comment: Is the error coming from the call to `np.array(array)` or from `scipy.io.wavfile.write`? Please add your stacktrace (or even your code) to your original post.

Comment: Its coming from `scipy.io.wavfile.write`. Its not much of a code that I have its really just that one call to `wavfile.write`.

Comment: Wait I know what it is. For some reason the last object in the array is a `None`. Thank you!

Comment: @user3151828 Make sure that your `array`, once it is converted to a numpy array is of a numeric type. Check that with `np.array(array).dtype`. If it's not something like np.float or similar, then your `array` is not just filled with numerical data. (also, try to avoid using such a generic name like `array`).

Comment: It returns `dtype('O')`. So I'm guessing that means object? Can I set the data type somehow, because I have gotten rid of all not numeric data, however it was after the array and its data type were created.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a bit of information in reply to user3151828's comment. I opened a file comprised of 32 bit signed float values, audio data not formatted as a proper wave file, and created a normal Python list and then converted it to a numpy array as Oliver W. states to do and printed the results.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import struct
file = open('audio.npa', 'rb')
i = 0
datalist = []
for i in range(4):
    data = file.read(4)
    s = struct.unpack('f', data)
    datalist.append(s)
numpyarray = np.array(datalist)
print('datalist, normal python array is: ', datalist, '/n')
print('numpyarray is: ', numpyarray)
```

The output is:

```
datalist, normal python list is:  [(-0.000152587890625,), (-0.005126953125,), (-0.010284423828125,), (-0.009796142578125,)]

numpyarray is:
[[-0.00015259]
[-0.00512695]
[-0.01028442]
[-0.00979614]]
```

So, there is the difference between the two.